# How to copy a pattern from one neck tie image to another that has a solid colour, in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, patterns, color-reproduction

I have a necktie with a pink solid color, that I want to use as a mockup:

[image]

[Source](http://prntscr.com/3qc2va)

And I have a number of neckties with various patterns like this:

[image]

[Source](http://prntscr.com/3qc3af)

How to copy the patterns from the patterned tie on top of a solid colour pink necktie, maintaining the integrity of the image, all the cringes, shapes and folds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:
-desaturate original object.
-mask the original object.
-make a pattern brush for each other pattern to be applied (also desaturated preferably).
-Paint pattern brush into masked area in a new layer with a multiply, screen or overlay layer.
-Add a solid color adjustment layer, so you are able to tint it back.

```
+---------+      
|         | <------- original desaturated     
|  +------+--+   
|  |         | <---- pattern brush filled layer (desaturated and masked)
|  |  +------+--+
+--+  |         | <- solid color (adjustment layer to tint final image)
   |  |         |
   +--+         |
      |         |
      +---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I should first explain that extracting the pattern from one photograph of a tie and painting it seamlessly onto another photo of a tie that's in a different position, is a very difficult task.

Even an experienced designer would probably not attempt this in the way you're suggesting. If anything, they'd probably redraw a template tie, then redraw each pattern flat, and apply it to the template.

Instead, as a quick and dirty fix for basic mockups, I'm suggesting a way for you to change the colour of the patterned ties to match the pink of the tie you want to overlay the patterns on.

1. Open the image you want to take the colour from in Photoshop.
2. Use the Eyedropper tool to select a good pink from the source image.
3. Paste the image you want to modify into the document. (It's the same size as the first image, so it's easy-squeezy in this case.)
4. Create a new <kbd>Solid Color..</kbd> layer.

   [image: Create solid color layer]
5. Change the blend mode to either <kbd>Screen</kbd>, <kbd>Hard Light</kbd>, <kbd>Linear Light</kbd> or <kbd>Color</kbd>, depending on which one is closest to what you want. It will look slightly different if you change the source colour, and you may find that a different blend mode suits you better.

   [image: Change the blend mode]

## Example Results:

#### Screen Blend Mode:

[image: Screen blend mode]

#### Hard Light Blend Mode:

[image: Hard light blend mode]

#### Linear Light Blend Mode:

[image: Linear light blend mode]

### Color Blend Mode:

[image: Color blend mode]

Comment: Or just CTRL+U and change Hue?